# Shell Script to Remotely Retrieve Red Hat subscription info

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to write a script to ssh to servers retrieved from a list and then report back the subscription-manager information. Here is the script I have but has issues:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVERLIST=`cat $HOME/Documents/RHEL_servers.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
SUBCOMMAND='sudo subscription-manager list --available'

#for HOSTS in $SERVERLIST; do echo $HOSTS;
#done

for HOSTS in $SERVERLIST; do ssh -t $HOSTS "($SUBCOMMAND)" > output.log;
done
```

What seems to be happening, by viewing that output.log, is that the script is hanging on the step to enter my password to launch the subscription-manager command but I don't see that. My assumption is that it is passing that to the connection on the remote machine and not on my side, I never see the option to enter my password.
Is there any way around this?
The end result that I hope for is to have the output of the subscription-manager list --available command piped to the output.log file sitting on my computer.

Comment: To be clear what I think it is getting stuck on is that redirect to the output.log. I can run same command via ssh -t without the redirect and get the output on my terminal.

Comment: The `(...)` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Although `sudo` writes its password prompt directly to its controlling terminal by default, that terminal is simply tied to your local `ssh` stdout. Your script is only hanging in the sense that it is waiting for a password to be entered; the prompt was written to the output log.

You should be able to pipe your password directly to `sudo` via `ssh`; you can also use the `-S` option to force `sudo` to read a password from its stdin instead.

Ideally, you could configure `sudo` on the remote hosts to run your command without requiring a password.

Comment: Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't recall exactly how `-t` works; you might simply be able to pipe your password to `ssh` for `sudo` to read. A better solution, if available, would be to configure `sudo` on the remote hosts to allow you to run that exact command without a password.

Comment: You can also use the `-S` option to force `sudo` to read the password from standard input.